# Select box text equal to rather than Select Box text contains - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two select boxes.

```
<select id="select-district">
    <option value="COL">COLOMBO</option>
    <option value="GAL">GALLE</option>
    <option value="MAT">MATARA</option>
    <option value="KEG">KEGALLE</option>
    <option value="KAND">KANDY</option>
    <option value="JAFF">JAFFNA</option>
</select>    

<select id="hidden-district">
    <option value="1">COLOMBO</option>
    <option value="2">GALLE</option>
    <option value="3">MATARA</option>
    <option value="4">KEGALLE</option>
    <option value="5">KANDY</option>
    <option value="6">JAFFNA</option>
 </select>
```

I also i have my jQuery code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-district').change(function() {
         var lngLatdist = $('#select-district option:selected').text();
        $("#hidden-district option:contains("+ lngLatdist +")").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

**And here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gAbf3/4/)**

The problem is when i select `GALLE` from `#select-district` it Shows `KEGALLE` on `#hidden-distrct`. Is there a way to select exact same word from the select boxes? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter` and also `.prop` ::

```
$("#hidden-district option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == lngLatdist;
}).prop("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your script like this it will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select-district').change(function() {
       var lngLatdist = $('#select-district option:selected').text();
       $("#hidden-district").val($("#hidden-district option:contains("+ lngLatdist +")").val());
  });
});
```

You need to set the value to change the drop down list value manually

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#select-district').change(function() {
        var lngLatdist = $('#select-district option:selected').text();
        $("#hidden-district option").each(function(){
             if($(this).text() == lngLatdist)
                 $(this).prop("selected","selected");
        });
    });
```